# What is this artifact from baking?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-painting, baking

This is following a recent bake,the bake when well except for the artifact over the ears.  Not sure why it happened, I did have separate items selected to one active mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the effect you get when you have 2 UVs in the exact same location.
If you're using the exact same UV on the other side, the bake gets info from both sides, giving these kinds of issues.
To fix this and still use the same UV, temporarily move 1 of the UVs of to the side of the UV-grid, bake your mesh, and move it back.

Comment: Did this fix your issue?